# How to set incoming call priority

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me about `the priority of incoming call screen`. I am developing an android application in which I want to show my `broadcastReceiver` instead of default screen.

Comment: show broadcastreceiver? It's not a view to show.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with **Normal BroadCast Receivers**

check this [BroadCast Receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

As discussed in the developer site. They are two types of Receivers

**Normal broadcasts** (sent with Context.sendBroadcast) are completely asynchronous. All receivers of the broadcast are run in an undefined order, often at the same time. This is more efficient, but means that receivers cannot use the result or abort APIs included here.

**Ordered broadcasts** (sent with Context.sendOrderedBroadcast) are delivered to one receiver at a time. As each receiver executes in turn, it can propagate a result to the next receiver, or it can completely abort the broadcast so that it won't be passed to other receivers. The order receivers run in can be controlled with the android:priority attribute of the matching intent-filter; receivers with the same priority will be run in an arbitrary order.

**Note**: This is taken from the above developer Site

Comment: can you please provide me a demo example